# get faces from video file using API in Azure Video Indexer

Tags: azure-video-indexer

how to get faces pictures using API from indexed file? I see only face detected green border, but want to extract face' pictures

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-video-indexer/face-detection.md), to extract face pictures, you'll need to use the face thumbnails provided in the Video Indexer output.

To download the face thumbnails, you can use the `Insight URL` with the following format:

```
https://api.videoindexer.ai/{location}/Accounts/{account_id}/Videos/{video_id}/Index?accessToken={access_token}&language=English
```

```py
import  requests
insights_url  =  f"https://api.videoindexer.ai/{location}/Accounts/{account_id}/Videos/{video_id}/Index?accessToken={access_token}&language=English"
insights_response  =  requests.get(insights_url)
insights_data  =  insights_response.json()
```

Once you have the `insights_response`, you can extract the `thumbnail_IDs` to get the pictures.

```py
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image

faces=insights_data['summarizedInsights']['faces']
for x,face in enumerate(faces):
    thumbnail_id=(face['thumbnailId'])
    artifact_url = f"https://api.videoindexer.ai/{location}/Accounts/{account_id}/Videos/{video_id}/Thumbnails/{thumbnail_id}?accessToken={access_token}"
    thumbnail_response = requests.get(artifact_url)
    image = Image.open(BytesIO(thumbnail_response.content))
    image.save(str(x)+'.jpg', 'JPEG')
    image.show()
```

With above steps and code snippet I was able to get required results.